# CherryPy: How to restrict a route to POST-only

Tags: python-3.x, http-post, cherrypy

I've a web-form that looks like:

```
<form action="/process_form/" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="login" value="login" />
  <input type="text" name="password" value="123" />
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

The python class to handle this is:

```
class Handle:
  @cherrypy.expose()
  #@cherrypy.tools.post <-- Is something like this possible
  def index(self, login=None):
    print(login)
```

Is there a way in CherryPy to restrict the call to `/process_form/` to POST method? I mean if a user types `http://www.example.com/process_form/` he/she should get an Exception/Error or page not found?

Comment: http://tools.cherrypy.org/wiki/HTTPMethodFiltering. Haven't really used `cherrypy` that much. However, flipping through the documentation yielded me this. Check if you find it useful.

Comment: CherryPy has native support for REST methods. Head for the documentation http://docs.cherrypy.org/dev/progguide/REST.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [Allow tool](https://docs.cherrypy.dev/en/latest/pkg/cherrypy.lib.cptools.html#cherrypy.lib.cptools.allow) will raise a 405.

```
@cherrypy.tools.allow(methods=['POST'])
```